# How GWT differs from JSF/Wicket in maintaing state and performance

Tags: jsf, gwt, wicket

I am new to GWT, JSF and Wicket. I am just wondering how GWT differs from maintaining client state from JSF/Wicket and also how performance differs under peek load. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, it doesn't differ. With all three you can either store the client state *on the client*, or *on the server* (in the http session).

- with GWT it is a bit more natural to store more things on the client side
- with JSF you have a configuration option to store all state on the client side
- with Wicket you have to do this yourself (as far as I know)

But with all of them you can use the `HttpSession`